# During takeoff, why throttle forward then raise hand from throttle to push a button, instead of pushing button then throttling?

Tags: takeoff, throttle

**Preface:** The comments assert the video to have been horizontally flipped, probably because (I am divining) the original belonged to someone else (user 'Jb380' if I remember)?

At 4 mins 3 secs of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryIbpHkeK2U), the captain (who appears in the video on the right, but per the preface above, should be on the left) pushes forward the throttle, but from which he then removes his hand to use this same hand to push a button that changes an instrument display,

- from showing the tail view (camera) of the aircraft (to assist with taxiing???),
- to the [primary flight display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_flight_display).

Afterward he replaces this hand back atop the throttle.

Why doesn't he instead push the button before deciding to takeoff and set takeoff thrust: this is safer than the above? For example, if abortion is decided exactly when nobody's hand is handling the throttle, then previous seconds needed to stop would be wasted?

Comment: You do know that unlike the throttle on a car or motorcycle, the throttle lever on an aeroplane stays put where it is set to, right?

Comment: @RoboKaren ...nonetheless the standard procedure in all aircraft I'm familiar with is to keep your hand on the throttle in the event you need to yank it back for an abort.

Comment: I know but wasn't sure if the OP knew either how the throttle worked or what the protocol was.

Comment: He probably realized that his MFD was still in camera mode when he looked down for airspeed.  At which point he had to change it to PFD mode because the airspeed tape is essential.

Comment: @RoboKaren Thanks. I do, yes.

Comment: Well, hopefully the throttle levers stay put...  It's best practice to guard the throttles to keep them from sliding back as they CAN slide back if the friction locks fail (which they do on rare occasions).  Still, not a big deal to move your hand to perform a necessary function, then put it back.

Comment: @JustinKiang: Essential?  The first flight lesson I had with my instructor, he slapped an instrument cover over the speed gauge and said "you won't be needing that".  Oil pressure is what you should be looking at on takeoff.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually he *does* push the button before selecting *takeoff* thrust.

Often<sup>1</sup> the procedure on jets during take-off is to move the thrust levers about half way, wait for the engines to spool up and only then select TO/GA or Flex thrust as desired. In the video the pilot switches the display during this intermediate step. So the engines are not even spooled up yet and the aircraft is still moving slow. Plenty of time to stop if anything fails.

In fact even when nearing v₁ the reaction does not need to be *that* fast. The calculation of v₁ includes 2 s reaction time and *correct* response is more important. Look e.g. on [this training video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-LSNsTIVLM) (it's A330, not A380, but the procedure is the same). The reaction is not *that* fast; they only retard the throttle after checking and calling the fault ("engine fire").

<sup>1</sup><sub>It used to be that the engines could flame out if you added fuel too quickly, but that's no longer the case now when engines are managed by FADEC (full authority digital engine computer). Some manufacturers/airlines/pilots maintain the procedure, most likely to avoid applying full power if one of the engines manifests some problem early. Or at least the pilot in *this* video does it.</sub>

Comment: On the emb145 you advance the thrust levers from idle straight into the detent with no need to pause. The FADEC handles a smooth spool up to the selected takeoff thrust setting.

Comment: @casey: Hm, it seems (from checking various cockpit videos) that the procedure is sometimes used and sometimes not and it does not seem consistent even for single aircraft type. Of course the original reason that the engine might flame out if fuel is added too quickly does not apply to engines controlled by FADEC, but it seems some keep the procedure to avoid asymmetric thrust (which isn't much concern in EMB-145 with tail-mounted engines) in case one engine lags behind or manifests some problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely normal in Aircrafts like the A380 , Boieing 777 etc . Hands off at V1 (Engine failure recognition speed) is perfectly proper in an aircraft with multiple engines.

The throttles still moves , however the power setting (EPR) is in the computer and the precise setting of the engines is automated. The Pilot Flying the aircraft will still feel the throttles vibrating under his hand, but it's the auto throttle doing it, and not the  flight engineer.

If Auto thrust is engaged, then there are 3 detents - Climb, Max Continuous/Flex and TOGA. 
If Autothrust is not engaged (at any time in the flight) then the thrust levers work just like the T/Ls on any other aircraft.

During take off, the T/Ls are placed either in TOGA (Take Off/Go Around) if  the pilot is doing a max power T/O, or in Flex/Max Continuous detent if the pilot is doing a Flex power T/O. When the levers are in either of these detents the FADEC (Full authority digital engine control) will give  the aircraft  the max power available for that selection (It depends on the ambient conditions). When the aircraft  reach the Thrust Reduction altitude the pilot may choose to  move the levers backwards to the Climb detent, and will then get Climb power. The levers remain in this detent until the pilot reduces thrust to idle in the flare during the landing . This means that the FADEC will give the aircraft whatever power is necessary to achieve what you are trying to do - climb power for the climb, or whatever thrust is necessary to achieve your cruising Mach number, or desired rate of descent or whatever.

If an engine fails, then the levers on the remaining engines are moved back into the Flex/Max Continuous detent, and the aircraft will get Max Continuous power. If the pilot has to do a go-around at the destination, the pilot puts the levers into the TOGA detent and the aircraft will get all the power available.

Comment: In Airbus the throttles _don't_ move. They don't have any servo for it. They are placed in the detent (TO/GA, MCT/FLX or CLB), which is a fixed position on Airbus, and FADEC does it's thing.

Comment: But you are not answering the question anyway. The question is about the very beginning of the take-off roll where pilot flying selects 50% power and _then_ moves his hand off to switch his primary display and back.

Comment: The question posed was related to the YouTube video and all that the asker wanted to know was is this tactic normal or is this a departure from normal conventions ? I have answered the question with the very first sentence of my [above] comment .

Comment: No, you said "Hands off at V1" and the question is about hands of at the very beginning of the take-off roll.

Comment: Hands off before V1 is possible in aircrafts like the A380.Once the throttle is advanced to the FLEX indent and A/THR is engaged the Engine Display should reflect " Power Set" . At this point it is ok if the pilot takes his hand off the throttle .

Answer (score 0):

Large engines, such as the ones on the A380 in the video, take time to accelerate. What the pilot in the video does is apply a small amount of power to ensure correct and balanced spool up of the engines. This prevents  an uneven application of takeoff thrust i.e. if one or more engines are slow to spool on one side.

This procedure will likely be detailed in the standard operating procedures of the airline, on the aircraft I fly we advance to 1.15 EPR prior to selecting takeoff thrust.

He moves his hand to start his stopwatch (the Chrono button on the Airbus), this is to keep track of the amount of time the engines stay at takeoff thrust. This is important to monitor as, for instance, during an engine failure you may need that power to clear terrain and your climb will be slower - you don't want to damage your remaining engine(s) by maintaining a high thrust level for too long.

On the RB211 we have a limit of 10 to 15 minutes depending on the aircraft variant.

He doesn't push the button before moving the thrust levers to ensure max available time at takeoff thrust.